# Cyrillic, AJAX and database

Tags: mysql, ajax, character-encoding

I save form data in a MySQL database with native AJAX.
In file 1 (where is the form and AJAX) I have

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

In file 2 (database submission) I have

```
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("output_encoding", "UTF-8");
iconv_set_encoding("input_encoding", "UTF-8");
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

+

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `rss` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci");
```

and I echo the variable from send AJAX - it is in Cyrillic .
The file encoding is UTF-8 without BOM.
Any ideas?
In DB - table collation - utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

instead of `SET CHARACTER SET`

Comment: Yes,I put them both.Thank You very much!